# Introductory text to Sobolev spaces and PDE's

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, textbook-recommendation

I'm looking for a good introductory to Sobolev, preferably with an emphasis to their relationship to PDE's analysis.

I have only seen thus far Giovanni Leoni's "First Course in Sobolev Spaces" which seems to me, from a first glance, more on the pure functional analysis side.

Thanks
Amir

Comment: http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~brezis/PUBlications/Functional%20Analysis_Flyer.pdf

Comment: I liked Rauch's book Partial Differential Equations. I looked at it frequently when I wrote my lecture notes on PDEs for a grad course that covering some Sobolev theory and a little pseudodifferential operators: http://euclid.ucc.ie/pages/staff/mckay/pde/introduction-to-partial-differential-equations.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Here is the order in which I think you should do things.

The pioneering book in the area is Non-Homogeneous Boundary Value Problems and Applications by Lions and Magness(springer).

Evans is the standard place to read about them. It is okay but he spends one page on the Fourier transform, and he uses all consuming powerful theorems before he needs to.  For a highly motivated treatment that emphasizes the Fourier transform, emphasizing the $L^2$ Sobolev spaces, I would very highly recommend Prof. Pierre Germain's Notes from PDE II, on his webpage.

After reading these notes if you want to read about elliptic regularity, you should read about it in Elliptic Partial Differential Equations by Fangua Lin. Or you could just jump into Fanghua Lin's book.

Other useful books I have found are Dememgel's Functional Spaces for the Theory of Elliptic Partial Differential Equations(springer).  It makes good use of the Fourier transform, and complement Pierre Germain's notes well.

It might not be a bad idea to learn some PDE too.  I would recommend Prof. Robert Kohn's lectures(PDE I) and problems.  They kept me up many a night and they some of the best I have found.

Comment: I visited Pierre Germain's page in the linke ahead, and didn't find the notes. Can you please link to them? http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~pgermain/indexenglish.html

Comment: I don't know him all that much. If you studied with him - can you contact him? It will be more natural, I guess...